# Azure Cmdlet Add-AzureRmAccount not working over corporate line

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm currently learning how to create azure environments using powershell Resource Management cmdlets.
The classic way of working had no problems, I could use `Add-AzureAccount` and it would allow me to access my subscriptions.

However, with the new Resource Manager cmdlets, when I use `Add-AzureRmAccount` I get either one of two errrors.

When using stored credentials using `$Cred = Get-Credentials`, and then logging in using `Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred` I receive the following error:

> Accessing ws metadata exchange failed.

When using the login prompt. Which means I just type in `Add-AzureRmAccount` and it forwards me to my company SSO page. In which I log in successfully. I get the following error:

> An error occurred while sending the request.

When I tried to use the cmdlet from home, using vpn to connect with the same laptop that I was using before. I can connect perfectly using `Add-AzureRmAccount` and following the logon prompts. Using the stored `$cred`entials still fails with the metadata exchange error.

I'm assuming that the stored credentials method is failing because it can't redirect to the SSO without the interactive prompt.
However I'm unsure what might be causing the interactive logon to fail, as I can clearly reach the SSO, and the `Add-AzureAccount` cmdlet works on the same machine.

What is the difference between the `Add-AzureAccount` and the `Add-AzureRmAccount` cmdlets that might be causing this?

**UPDATE:**

The full stack trace error is:

```
Message        : An error occurred while sending the request.
Data           : {}
InnerException : System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
                    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                    at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
TargetSite     : Void ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
StackTrace     :    at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                    at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
                    at Microsoft.Azure.Subscriptions.TenantOperationsExtensions.List(ITenantOperations operations)
                    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient.ListAccountTenants(AzureAccount
                 account, AzureEnvironment environment, SecureString password, ShowDialog promptBehavior)
                    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient.Login(AzureAccount account,
                 AzureEnvironment environment, String tenantId, String subscriptionId, String subscriptionName,
                 SecureString password)
                    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureRMAccountCommand.ProcessRecord()
                    at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord()
                    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
HelpLink       :
Source         : Microsoft.Threading.Tasks
HResult        : -2146233088
```

It looks like my error is firewall related.
I'm unsure why the one command (`Add-AzureRmAccount`) encounters the error while the older version (`Add-AzureAccount`) does not.

Comment: need more detail from the errors.  Post the output of this `$error[0].exception | fl -f`

Comment: is there a proxy/ firewall in between trying to read the encrypted traffic?  I've seen all sorts of weird issues when companies "inspect" the secured traffic.

Comment: Most likely the difference between the cmdlets is that the new one is using a web based api.

Comment: @Colyn1337 Thx, found a solution now.

Comment: @JimB Apparently the proxy server when in the office is a different one to the one that is used when accessing through VPN. The difference in their configuration means I needed to connect differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment made by [Colyn1337](https://serverfault.com/users/185923/colyn1337) about the difference being likely a web based api.
And the authentication error being related to a proxy server not authenticating correctly.

A similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818672/how-can-i-run-an-azure-powershell-cmdlet-through-a-proxy-server-with-credentials) where a different, also web based api cmdlet, had a similar error, provided the solution.
As mentioned in [the answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14858667/4337899) I simply have to add the following code at the start of my scripts:

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
```